# [BHO][IE11] Capture event newtab

Tags: internet-explorer-11, bho

I am developing projects on ie-addons.
I want to record the new tab action when the user clicks the A tag or the script calls `window.open (url, '_ blank') ;`.
I used `OnNewWindow2` / `OnNewWindow3`. However, some win7 and win10 machines do not work. When running on the dev machine (win7, vs2017, ie11), it works very stable.
I don't know why and is there any other way to capture this event on all computers.
I am developing the application on win7 / 10 and ie11

Thank you

Comment: Did you got any error when it does not work on other machine? Did you find any difference in the configuration of both machine? If possible than try to post your sample code. We will try to test it on our side to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I cannot provide Source for you.
I noticed that if protected mode is disable it will work. However, on a dev machine with the option to enable protected mode it still works.

Comment: This is my example
public int SetSite([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object site)
{
 try
 {
  if (site != null)
  {
   webBrowser = (WebBrowser)site;
   webBrowser.NewWindow3 += new DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3EventHandler(OnNewWindow);
  }
  else
  {
   webBrowser.NewWindow3 -= new DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3EventHandler(OnNewWindow);
   webBrowser = null;
  }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
  // out msg
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: private void OnNewWindow(ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel, uint dwFlags, string bstrUrlContex, string strUrl)
{
 string strPageId = record.GetPageID(document);
 string strBankCode = record.GetBankCode(document);
 socket.sendMsg(Constant.TYPE_ACTION.RECORD, new MsgRecorder(Constant.TYPE_ACTION.SWITCH_BROWSER, String.Empty, String.Empty, String.Empty, strPageId, strBankCode));
}

Comment: For testing purpose, try to lower down the security levels of settings in Internet options to check whether it solves this issue or not. It can be possible that if security levels are high than code get failed.